# Finding CLT for Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution

It seems like a lot of examples for estimating the confidence intervals of a Gamma distribution, the parameter estimation involve one variable being known. I was wondering how to find a confidence interval for the MLE of the rate and scale parameters of a Gamma distribution.

Suppose we have $X_i\sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, one can easily find the MLE estimators by solving:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\alpha}{\lambda} &= \bar{x} \\
\log{\alpha} - log{\bar{x}}- \psi(\alpha)+\overline{\log{x}}&=0
\end{align*}
where $\psi(\alpha)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\log{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ and we solve the second equation numerically to ultimately get estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. My question is how exactly do we then get a confidence interval of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I am thinking that I can find the Fisher Information Matrix to get that $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta})\sim N([\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}]^T, \mathbf{I^{-1}(\theta)})$, where $\mathbf{I^{-1}(\theta)}$ is the Fisher Information Matrix which can be found relatively easily. However, given that this Matrix has covariance terms, I was wondering how I would go about forming a confidence interval, or whether this is the correct approach to begin with.

Comment: What do you mean by a confidence interval for two parameters?  Do you want a rectangle with the probability of  the rectangle covering the true values simultaneously  being $95\%$? Or do you want two intervals with each having a $95\%$  probability of covering its true value (noting their product will be smaller than the earlier rectangle)?  Or do you want some other shape of "interval"?

Comment: @Henry I’m mainly looking for the second, two intervals with each having 95% probability of covering true value

Comment: Thinking about it further, I think the two parameters are too correlated for this approach to be helpful (unless there is some specific physical meaning you want to attach to them in a particular case) and you might do better with confidence intervals for the mean and variance and then say you can find the two parameters from these without putting confidence intervals on them.  Unless $\alpha$ is small, the gamma distribution is close to normal.